# Trouble in understanding how for loops interact with arrays in c++ [homework]

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

My teacher gave us the a code where a user inputs a number up to 10 digits, and each digit is stored in an array. We need to format it in such a way that it outputs each digit that is repeated individually. I'm trying to accomplish this using a for loop, but I'm having some difficulty in understanding exactly how the loop interacts with the array (or at least, I think that's where my trouble is coming from). This is where I'm at so far... Anyone that can explain the interaction of the for loop and array between lines 44 and 50 will have my appreciation.

```
#include <iostream> // provides cin, cout, endl, fixed

using namespace std;

#define DIGITS 10 // number of Base 10 digits

int main()
{
    // declaration section

    int number,                 // number input by the user
        digit,                  // digit of number being processed
        digit_tally[DIGITS],    // keeps track of digits seen
        i;                      // general array-element counter

    // Initialize digit tally to all zeroes, indicating that no repeated digits have been found

    for (i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++)
    {
        digit_tally[i] = 0;
    }

    // input section

    cout << "Enter a number (any negative number to exit): ";
    cin >> number;

    // processing section

    while (number > 0) 
    {
        digit = number % 10;

        if (digit_tally[digit] == 0)
        {
            digit_tally[digit] = 1;

        }
        else if (digit_tally[digit] == 1)
        {
            cout << "Repeated digits: ";

            for (digit_tally[digit] = 1; digit_tally[digit] <= 10; digit_tally[digit]++)
                cout << number << " ";
        }

        number = number / 10;
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

For reference, the output should look something like this:

Enter a number (any negative number to exit): 64246

Repeated digits: 4 6

Answer (score 1):

As you have got the logic of storing the number of occurrences in the index. You can proceed with that approach and once you finish lopping through the entire number, have another loop that prints the index that has more than 1 occurrence.

```
while (number > 0)
 {
        digit = number % 10;
        digit_tally[digit -1] += 1;
        number = number / 10;
        cout << endl;
 }

 for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
 {
    if (digit_tally[i] > 1)
    {
       std::cout << i + 1 << " ";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, so it wouldn't be possible to do it with a for loop within the main loop? I should make an entirely new loop to print out each individual number?

Comment: You don't have to, after digit_tally is incremented you could check if it equals 2, and spit it out if it does. You don't want >=2 because you don't want to repeat numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (digit_tally[digit] = 1; digit_tally[digit] <= 10; digit_tally[digit]++)
                cout << number << " ";
```

This takes the value at digit_tally[digit], sets it to 1, then runs the loop while it goes 1 through 10, and will just spit out the same number over and over.

If you want to loop through the array, you'd set it up like the first for loop (and it's important that you start from 0 and that you have < DIGITS, not <=.

Don't be confused, all loops can accomplish the same tasks with some minor tweaks.

```
 for (i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++)
    {
        digit_tally[i] = 0;
    }
```

is semantically the same as

```
i = 0
while (i < DIGITS)
{
    digit_tally[i] = 0;
    ++i
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see how the for loop works in your first example. I'm still having difficulty getting it to output correctly. For example, if I use the example you gave and input 1166 I get 1's in the (1) and (6) block of the array showing that those are repeated, but not the actual numbers that were put into the array. The fact that I'm getting a full printout of the array and the repeated numbers are blocked off is an improvement, thanks for that.

Comment: Does Jagganath's answer work for you? I believe it should. Your original approach correctly found the digit, checked if it had come up before, and made the array element increment by 1. Well, almost, arrays in C++ start at 0, so you really need digit - 1 in the array element. But then if the digit repeated, you tried to output it, which is where I think your problem was. Actually, if you just want to use your approach, you can check if the digit - 1 element == 1, then output digit, then increment digit -1. No loops necessary there. That's similar to my suggestion in jaggonath's answer

Comment: Oh man, that did it! I took out the loop and just output the digit and bingo! XD guess I was overthinking it the entire time. Though I didn't have to start the digit at -1. I took out the loop and just left this 

        cout << digit << " ";
        digit = digit +1;

Thanks for the help!